# VS Code - Intellisense stopped working, takes 4-5 seconds to save a file

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, emmet

For seemingly no reason at all, VS Code is suddenly a heap of garbage - autocomplete/Emmet/IntelliSense no longer appear and it takes 4-5 seconds to save any file.

I haven't changed anything, and it all appears to have happened by itself. How can I figure out what it's doing?

### Edit

I might add I've deleted all its cache files, closed and reopened, rebooted my computer etc. Nada.

Comment: Vscode updated today.  What version are you on now?

Comment: 1.54.1 (presumably most recent). It started yesterday though, so it was around before this update.

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to VS Code update
I will suggest you to first turn of the auto update option
So that in future you have more control over it.

```
go to File > Preferences > Settings (macOS: Code > Preferences > Settings), search for update mode and change the setting to none.
```

Now  to Fix This you have to do somethings as Hard Way ,

You are already Using some intelliSense so you need to reload your extensions or Update them if available.

Second :

```
No Need to restart VSCode you can reload the window
ctrl + shift + P 
then select reload window by typing in the box
```

NOTE : This will all work if you are not making a remote connection if you are on remote then you need to delete .vscode folder from the home directory and have to reinitiate the connection

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [auto-save](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save) parameter in `settings.json` called `files.autoSaveDelay` to a lower value might help. The value is in milliseconds.